# TypeError : Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

while doing an exercise from my coding class, i keep getting this error and i can't seem to figure out why. i wanted the name with the most 'ha's to show up.

for now, the output is correct but the error won't go away.

```
function haCounter(arr) {
  if (arr){
var jmlHa = arr.match(/ha/g) || []
return jmlHa.length
  }
  else {
    return 0
  }

}

function theLaughter(arr) {
  var result = arr.reduce(function (x,y){

    console.log ((haCounter(x[1]) > haCounter(y[1])) ? x[0] : y[0] )

 }
)
return result
}
```

the test-case and the desired output:

```
console.log(theLaughter([
  ['Tony', 'haha, get lost, squidward!'],
  ['Mantis', 'hahahahahahaha'],
  ['Thanos', 'I am inevitable'],
  ['Rocket', 'Boom! hahahaha']
])) // 'Mantis'
```

i tried returning the ternary like this, but it returns 'Rocket' intead of 'Mantis'.

```
function theLaughter(arr) {
  var result = arr.reduce(function (x,y){

    return ((haCounter(x[1]) > haCounter(y[1])) ? x[0] : y[0] )

 }
)
return result
}
```

here's the pointer that comes along with the error:

```
console.log ((haCounter(x[1]) > haCounter(y[1])) ? x[0] : y[0] )
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `.reduce` callback, so on subsequent iterations, `x` is `undefined`. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: is the purpose of your program to return the name with the most 'ha's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. This method returns the character with the most amount of laughs.

```
function mostLaughs(input){
  var most = (input[0][1].match(/ha/g) || []).length;
  var name = input[0][0]
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if((input[i][1].match(/ha/g) || []).length > most){
      most = (input[i][1].match(/ha/g) || []).length;
      name = input[i][0]
    }
  }
  return name;
}

console.log(mostLaughs([
  ['Tony', 'haha, get lost, squidward!'],
  ['Mantis', 'hahahahahahaha'],
  ['Thanos', 'I am inevitable'],
  ['Rocket', 'Boom! hahahaha']
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works, it passes the return value from the previous callback into the next call to the callback as the first argument. So your `reduce` callback must always return a useful value.

```js
const result = [6, 4, 1].reduce((x, y) => {
    const rv = x + y;
    console.log(`x = ${x}, y = ${y}, returning ${rv}`);
    return rv;
});
console.log(`result = ${result}`);
```

Your callback doesn't return anything, so it effectively returns `undefined`. Since it returns `undefined` on the first call, `x` is `undefined` on the second call. Here's the above without the return:

```js
const result = [6, 4, 1].reduce((x, y) => {
    const rv = x + y;
    console.log(`x = ${x}, y = ${y}, not returning ${rv}`);
});
console.log(`result = ${result}`);
```

I can't quite figure out what you want your callback to do, so I don't know what it should return, but effectively:

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(x,y) {
    console.log((haCounter(x[1]) > haCounter(y[1])) ? x[0] : y[0] );
    return /*something here */;
});
```